# How to remove special characters from JSON through esql

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am facing issue with Special characters coming in input json message. See below sample, how to remove/convert them in esql. In the below sample issue is with '`Â°`'.

```json
"Creator": {
            "Name": {
                "FullName": "Dummy"
            }
        },
"Description": "dummy dummy dummy : 41.5Â°C.\nextention 100% b ...",
```

Answer (score 0):

The Description field is just a standard field in the message tree, so you can use the standard ESQL string-processing functions: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/app-connect/11.0.0?topic=functions-esql-string-manipulation